# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

Sei que o problema é simples.. mas não estou conseguindo resolver
minha variável Batimentos só aparece na segunda view, mas uma função acaba chamando ela na primeira view,
só preciso verificar se ela esta aparecendo, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o if de controle

```
@IBOutlet weak var Batimentos: UILabel!


if let actualBpm = bpm{
            print(actualBpm)

            Batimentos.text! = "\(actualBpm)"

        }else {
            print("ELSE bpm")
        }
```

Comment: Se você está atribuindo um valor à label "Batimentos", não é necessário fazer o force unwrap. Talvez esse seja o problema, porque possivelmente no momento da atribuição o texto é nil e você está forçando...

Answer (score -1):

Tenta dessa forma.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Batimentos: UILabel!


if let actualBpm = bpm{
    print(actualBpm)

    Batimentos.text! = "\(actualBpm!)"

}else {
    print("ELSE bpm")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O `force unwrap` no atributo text é desnecessário, pois você está atribuindo um valor.
Tenta assim, retirando o force unwrap:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var batimentos: UILabel!

if let actualBpm = bpm{
  print(actualBpm)
  batimentos.text = "\(actualBpm)"
} else {
  print("ELSE bpm")
}
```